# Visual Studio 2013 error MSB6001

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2013, citrix

I am building a C project in Visual Studio 2013 and sometimes it works but other times it fails with error (it just fails randomly):

> 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(607,5):
>   error MSB6001: Invalid command line switch for "link.exe". Not a valid
>   Win32 FileTime.
>
> 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(607,5):
>   error MSB6001: Parameter name: fileTime

If I get this error I normally just try rebuilding several times and all of a sudden the error disappears (without making any changes to the code) and I get a successful build. I find this very peculiar.

Everything worked fine until I installed Citrix Receiver. Is there a known conflict with Citrix Receiver or is it just a coincidence? Has any of you experienced something similar? Is there a fix for it?

Comment: It is a known problem: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/635940/invalid-command-line-switch-for-link-exe-when-building

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, uninstalling the "Citrix offline Plug-In" (using the standard Windows uninstall procedure) solved the problem. Btw. this did not affect the "Citrix Workspace", which I regularly use.